# jQuery .submit function not returning appropriate value after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

So what I'm getting at here is pretty straight forward:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var loc = $("input#location").val();
    var response = $.ajax({
        url: "checklocation.php",
        data: {loc: loc},
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg['status'] == "OK") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return !(response['responseText'].indexOf("ZERO_RESULTS") != -1);
});
```

checklocation.php returns a json String. Neither of the returns are hit, however if I throw an alert() in either, the conditional does indeed work. But, if I step through this in Firebug, it would appear as though the stuffs in the success function are never executed.

This just returns true every time, no matter what (the form is submitted).

EDIT:
Even after simplifying:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var loc = $("input#location").val();
    var response = $.ajax({
        url: "checklocation.php",
        data: {loc: loc},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg == '1') {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It still skips over the success function, despite the statusText of response being 'success.'

Comment: have you tried with complete and error callbacks? Because `success` will be executed only if the response come with 200 or 2xx family status code. It will be better to use    `done, fail, always` instead as of JQuery 1.8 deprecation.

Comment: I have tried, and it won't get there. I can see clearly in Firebug that the response has a 200 status code and a "success" status text.

Comment: why you are using `async : false` ? does it make sense? also deprecated in JQuery 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `async:false`, As of my guess the possible fix will be,

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var loc = $("input#location").val();
    var response = $.ajax({
        url: "checklocation.php",
        data: {loc: loc},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg['status'] == "OK") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            return !(response['responseText'].indexOf("ZERO_RESULTS") != -1);
        },
    });        
});
```

The problem might be occurred because of

`return !(response['responseText'].indexOf("ZERO_RESULTS") != -1);`

might have been executed before the success callback executed, actually at this point the `response['responseText']` is undefined. But you will get the response , because the ajax request already sent.

Answer (score 0):

Like thujeevan points out the last line is executed before the ajax has had time to finish so the response variable is in the process of being made when the function checks it and returns.

The best way for this to work is to replace the submit button with a normal button and when that button is clicked this check is run. Then you put another code into the submit action for the form that only submits if the check has been done and it was ok.

Somthing like this:

```
<form method="post" id="theform">
<input type="text" id="location" />
<input type="button" id="button_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
 var ok = false;

 $('#button_submit').click(function () {
  var loc = $('input#location').val();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'checklocation.php',
   data: {loc: loc},
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(msg) {
    ok = (msg['status'] == "OK");
   },
   error: function () {
    ok = false;
   }
  });
  $('#theform').submit();
 });

 $('#theform').submit(function () {
  return ok;
 });
</script>
```

Hope this helps! ;)